# ArrayList: IndexOutOfBounds exception issue

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a program to find prime numbers. I'm storing the prime numbers and all positive integers (right now till 100) in two `ArrayList<Integer>`. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PrimeNumbers { 
static ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> prime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    prime.add(2);
    prime.add(3);
    prime.add(5);
    for (int z = 1; z<=100; z++){
        num.add(z);
    }
    outer: for (int a = 1; a <=num.size(); a++){
        inner: for (int b = 1; b <=prime.size(); b++){
            if (num.get(a)%prime.get(b) != 0){//line 14
                if (prime.indexOf(b)+1 == prime.size()){
                    prime.add(a);
                    continue outer;
                }
                else 
                    continue inner;
            }
            else
                continue outer;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prime);

    }
}
```

But when I run the program, these errors show up:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
>   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>   at PrimeNumbers.main(PrimeNumbers.java:14)

What is going wrong?

Comment: You might be interested in my short [java debugging tutorial](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/). I even use IndexOutOfBoundsException as an example. Also, you probably shouldn't use goto's (continue x).

Comment: gotos as in continue?

Comment: Yes, as in the directed continues you're using, along with labels. It's more or less a relic.

Comment: can you tell me another way?

Comment: Yes, you simply use `continue` and `break` and write your code so that it works with those.

Comment: I even suggest using `break` instead of `goto` or `continue outer`...

Comment: Java 101: array indexes run from `0` to `size()-1`. Your code assumes the first element is `1`, and the last one is `size()`, which is where you try to access an **index out of bounds**.

Comment: it is still just showing the initial list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List indices run from 0 to `size()-1`, but you are looping from 1 to `size()`.

Comment: Rewrite your loops like this: `for (int a = 0; a <num.size(); a++)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of a `Collection` has index `0`, not `1`. Thus for example, accessing the third element should be done as `collection.get(2)`.

Your loops should iterate like follows:

```
outer: for (int a = 0; a < num.size(); a++){
    inner: for (int b = 0; b < prime.size(); b++){
        ...
    }
}
```

Note the strict (`<`) index comparison. Moreover, there is the following simpler way:

```
outer: for (Integer numItem : num){
    inner: for (Integer primeItem : prime){
        ...
    }
}
```

This `for` loop form iterates on the whole collection.

Comment: You overlooked changing `<=` to `<`.

Comment: i changed them but it is not returning the prime numbers between 0 and 100, it is just showing the starting list ([2,3,5])

Comment: Your problem might not be Java related. Advice to you: take the habit of thinking/writing down your algorithm before coding it

Answer (score 0):

Try using Double instead of Integer. (Note how Double is an Object with a capital "D").